# How can I change the color of a line chart segment in chart.js 2 depending on if it is a positive or negative slope?

Tags: chart.js, sveltekit, stock

I am currently trying to make a stock tracker chart (I know its basic but I'm still learning) in sveltekit.
At the current state I have no problem generating a basic graph where the line is all one color, but I would like segments with a positive slope to be green and negative slopes to be purple.

So far I have tried 2 implementations

```
function generateGradient(ctx, stockData) {
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);

    for (let i = 1; i < stockData.length; i++) {
      const color = getLineColor(stockData[i - 1], stockData[i]);
      const position = i / (stockData.length - 1);
      gradient.addColorStop(position, color);
    }

    return gradient;
  }

  function initializeChart() {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const chartLabels = stockData.map((item) => item.datetime.slice(0, 10));
    const chartData = stockData.map((item) => parseFloat(item.close));
    // const gradientStroke = generateGradient(ctx, stockData);

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#80b6f4");
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "#f49080");

    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: chartLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Stock Price',
            data: chartData,
            // borderColor: getLineColor(),
            borderColor: gradientStroke,
            borderWidth: 3, // line width
            pointRadius: 2, // point radius
            fill: false,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      },
    });
  }
```

This generates different gradients stop-points depending on if the line segment is positive or negative, which will result in a wonky gradient but it just causes an error in chart.js. I am not sure exactly where the issue is coming from, but I would appreciate any help.

My second implementation is thus

```
function generateSegmentedDatasets(stockData) {
        const datasets = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < stockData.length; i++) {
        const color = getLineColor(stockData[i - 1], stockData[i]);
        const data = Array(i - 1).fill(null).concat(stockData[i - 1].close, stockData[i].close).concat(Array(stockData.length - i - 1).fill(null));
        datasets.push({
            label: `Segment ${i}`,
            data,
            borderColor: color,
            borderWidth: 3,
            pointRadius: 2,
            fill: false,
            tension: 0,
        });
        }
        return datasets;
    }

function initializeChart() {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const chartLabels = stockData.map((item) => item.datetime.slice(0, 10));
        const chartData = generateSegmentedDatasets(stockData);

        chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: chartLabels,
            datasets: chartData,
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
        },
   });
}
```

This should in theory generate entirely different line segments with different colors, but I dont think my knowledge of chartjs is enough to tell if this is even a viable solution, and I kinda just coded it all in one go without testing along the way (again please take it easy on me this is a first time project)

Both implementations follow an onmount func that grabs data from a .json I have stored in the project directory for ease of use.

This is also being done in sveltekit which adds an extra layer of complication, but I doubt thats the problem.

Comment: There was a bug in chart.js to manage gradients on the segments. There is already a PR to solve it and the original issue is the following: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/11204 I think it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The Chart.js documentation has an example showing what you want done using [segments](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/segments.html).

The key there is the `segment` definition (simplified to get rid of the `skipped` modifier to focus on the `down` modifier):

```js
segment: {
  borderColor: ctx => down(ctx, 'rgb(192,75,75)'),
},
```

and its corresponding helper:

```js
const down = (ctx, value) => ctx.p0.parsed.y > ctx.p1.parsed.y ? value : undefined;
```

So what does this do? For each segment `[p0, p1]` in your dataset, the `down` helper is called. If `p0 > p1` (i.e. segment is sloping *down*), then the helper will return a color value (which is hard set to `rgb(192,75,75)` in the code) and affect it to the `borderColor` attribute *for this segment*.

Otherwise the helper function will return `undefined` and the segment (which is sloping *up*) will default to its default configuration (which, in the example linked above, is `borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'`).

In order to put all of this together in Svelte, all we need to do is declare a `canvas` element to hold our chart, get a reference to it with [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-this), and create the chart within [`onMount()`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount) to make sure the canvas has been mounted and its reference is available:

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
    let canvas;
    
    const down = (ctx, value) => ctx.p0.parsed.y > ctx.p1.parsed.y ? value : undefined;

    const genericOptions = {
        fill: false,
        interaction: {
            intersect: false
        },
        radius: 0,
    };

    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Price chart',
                data: [65, 59, 40, 48, 56, 57, 40],
                borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                segment: {
                    borderColor: ctx => down(ctx, 'rgb(192,75,75)'),
                },
            }]
        },
        options: genericOptions
    };
    
    onMount(() => {
        const chart = new Chart(canvas, config);
    });
</script>

<div style="width: 800px;">
    <canvas bind:this={canvas}></canvas>
</div>
```

[Demo REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f9d1eb8177d84c1fba1cab5a564120b2?version=3.58.0)